# Oxid Enterprise Edition 5.2 Import Variant Article Prices

Tags: mysql, database, import, field, oxid

i have to import a CSV file of variant article prices for a oxid enterprise edition 5.2.X. As it's several years ago i worked with oxid, iam a bit confused, because as i know, the prices shoudle be imported into the mysql table "oxfield2shop" but when i try to import them or take a look at the oxprice/a/b/c field configuration it will be truncated because the fields are of type double with length/set 22,0. But manually added prices out of the backend seems to work... maybe i forgot something or oversaw it, does someone have a clue?

[image]

[image]

Thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just set price directly into the table articles. It also has columns: oxshopid, oxprice, oxpricea,... and I attach the DB schema of oxid CE 4.9, it corresponding with EE 5.2.

[image]